# Trying to enqueue a js file and run a function inside it on form submit, using php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Having problems with getting this javascript function to run on form submit:

**The contents of the js file:**

```
function validateForm(){

var x = document.forms["newTicket"]["back"].value;
if(x == "submit"){
    var x = document.forms["newTicket"]["ticket_description"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Description must not be empty");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**The register and enqueue script calls:**

```
wp_register_script('scripts', plugins_url() . '/js/scripts.js');
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
```

**The html form:**

```
echo '<form action="" method="POST" name="newTicket" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
Description: <textarea class="widget" rows="4" cols="1" placeholder="Input here" name="ticket_description" ></textarea>
<input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<input class="btn" type="submit" name="back" value="home">
</form>';
```

The javascript should check to make sure:
1. the back button was not clicked
2. the description field is not empty

What's am I doing wrong here?

Comment: function never returns `true`, and only returns anything under one specific condition. Also `back` has value `"home"` so can never equal `"submit"`

Comment: @charlietfl - Ok I've made the changes that you suggested but still nothing is happening when I click the submit button the function now look like this: `function validateForm(){
  var x = document.forms["newTicket"]["ticket_description"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
   alert("Description must not be empty");
   return false;
  }else{
  return true;
  }
}`

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/r8nevtvj/

Comment: Am I using the enqueue scripts correctly?

Comment: did you include that inside a wordpress action hook? Use network tab of browser dev tools to see if script is even loading

Comment: I have it like this: `function register_my_scripts(){
wp_register_script('scripts', plugins_url() . '/js/scripts.js');
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_script','register_my_scripts');` I don't think i can see the script in the network tab.

Comment: but where do you call `register_my_scripts()`? Needs to be in a hook like:  `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts');`

Comment: The add_action is exactly what I have underneath the function

Comment: my bad..I missed it, hard reading code in comments sometimes. WHere are you using that in child theme `functions.php`?

Comment: I'm using it in a custom plugin. Sorry I should have made that clear.

Comment: ohhh I fixed it. I'm not using the plugins_url() correctly. correct syntax is `wp_register_script('scripts', plugins_url('/js/scripts.js', __FILE__));`